# jQuery Time Refresh

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery countdown timer at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I am trying to get the time remaining to refresh automatically without reloading the page. It is getting the remaining time from a MySQL DB and if I change the value in the DB the time still countdowns from the original time. I have an onTick event which checks a script for the new time.

If I use the destroy command the script attaches multiple times for every onTick.

Is there a way to reinitialize the timer without reload?

Cheers

Comment: Please post the code that you have now so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it should be no problem to just go:

```
$("#timer").countdown("destroy").countdown({ until: newDate, onTick: checkTime });
```

It works here:  http://jsfiddle.net/YA4BW/.  Note that the tick counter still only increments by one per second after the timer has been destroyed and re-initialized.  When you initialize the timer, the first `onTick` event is immediate, so you will effectively get a second `onTick` event for the same second when you re-initialize.